# How to end a loop when the value is 0?

Tags: java, loops

How do I get a loop to go infintly but have it end when the value reaches 0? I want the process to end when the int money reaches 0. I am not that familiar with loops so sorry if this question is dumb.

```
System.out.println(list.get(0).array[3]);

for (int a = 10; a <= 1; a = a - money)
{
    System.out.println("Enter in a vaule you want to bet out of $" + money + "");
    String moneyvalue = Input.next();

    int i = Integer.parseInt(moneyvalue);// i is the user input for
                                            // amount of money they want
                                            // to bet
    int x = money;// total money

    if (i > x)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an acceptable value from 1-" + x);
    }

    if (i <= x)
    {

        System.out.println("Which horse do you want to win, enter in 1-5");
        String horsechoice = Input.next();

        int randomhorse = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        int horsechoice1 = Integer.parseInt(horsechoice);
        System.out.println(randomhorse);

        if (horsechoice1 == randomhorse)
        {
            System.out.println("You win");
            money = x + i;
            System.out.println("You have $" + money + " remaining.");
        }

        else if (horsechoice1 > 5)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry try again.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You Lose");
            money = x - i;
            System.out.println("You have $" + money + " remaining.");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can declare it in your for loop

```
for (int a = 10; a <=1, money > 0; a = a - money) {...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If( money ==0)
   Break;
```

The break statement will get you out of the loop
You can place in last else where you are assigning money a new number

or you do this

```
for (int a = 10; a <=1, money > 0; a = a - money)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = money;

while(x>0)
{
   // your code here
}
```

or

```
int x;
for(;;)
{
   x = money;
   // your code here
   // ...
   //

   if(x<=0) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int money = 1000;//Initialize your value
while(money != 0){
    //do some gambling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing with the for(a...) loop.  I think you really just trying to construct the following loop:

```
while(money > 0)
{
   // do some stuff!
}
```